# Qr read and generation under QT creator using leadtools

Tags: c++, qt, qr-code, leadtools-sdk

I want to buy license for QR codes read and generating from [Leadtools](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/barcode-pro.htm) but first I want to try their demo tools. **I'm using MSVC 2013 x64 compiler.** I think I did everything as follows in documentation:

1. Copied all dll's to my project directory (where build and release folder are located)
2. Copied Include and Lib folders to my project directory and add this lines to .pro file.

`LIBS += -L$$PWD/Lib/CDLLVC12/x64/ -lLtkrn_x
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Include
PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/Bin/CDLLVC12/x64/Ltkrnx.dll`

3. include  and #define LTV19_CONFIG, here is my code:

   ```
   #define LTV19_CONFIG
   #include <iostream>
   #include <Ltkrn.h>
   #include <ClassLib/LtWrappr.h>
   using namespace std;

   int main( ){
   if( LT_KRN == LBase::LoadLibraries( LT_KRN, LT_DLGKRN))
       cout << "success" << endl;

   L_TCHAR licenseFile[] = L"d:\\temp\\TestLic.lic";
   L_TCHAR key[] = L"xyz123abc";
   LSettings::SetLicenseFile( licenseFile, key);

   return 0;
   }
   ```
4. Ask leadtools support, but they don't have much experience with working with QT...

When I tries to build application I get following errors:

```
    LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned int __cdecl LBase::LoadLibraries(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (__imp_?LoadLibraries@LBase@@SAIII@Z) referenced in function main
    LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static int __cdecl LSettings::SetLicenseFile(wchar_t *,wchar_t *)" (__imp_?SetLicenseFile@LSettings@@SAHPEA_W0@Z) referenced in function main
```

For following methods documentation says that I only need one dll/lib package (ltkrn). How to fix it? Still I don't get differences between static and dynamic linkage and this could be the problem.

Comment: All these dll should be specified in your `LIBS` directory.

Comment: What do you mean? [Documentation](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/main/clib/lbase__loadlibraries.html) said that I only need LTKRN (dll, lib and .h files) for this functions

Comment: Documentation says about `LTKRN` library, why are you linking against `Ltkrn_x` ? What does `_x` means?

Comment: [Here](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/main/clib/14files.html) is what files have to be included. _x stands for x64 version (I will edit my post that I'm using msvc x64 compiler).

Answer (score 0):

If your linker accepted the 64-bit Ltkrn_x.lib, this suggests the problem is related to how you're using LEADTOOLS and not to QT. That's why I'm posting this as suggested reply instead of a note.
When programming using LEADTOOLS with C++, you normally use one of 2 sets of headers and LIBs:

1. Either include L_Bitmap.H (or a bunch of headers that includes LtKrn.H)  and use the Ltkrn_x, Ltfil_x, etc. set of LIB files.
2. Or include ClassLib\LtWrappr.h and use only one LIB file, which in your case is Ltwvc_x.lib

Although in both cases you would be using many of the same DLL files such as Ltfilx.dll and Ltkrnx.dll, the reason you don't need their LIB files when using LtWrapper is that the ClassLibrary performs late (on demand) loading of these DLLs at run-time instead of referencing their LIB files at link time.

That's also why you need to call LBase::LoadLibraries() and specify the DLLs you need before your code uses these DLLs.
So to summarize, please try this:

- Remove #include "Ltkrn.h"
- Remove the linker reference to Ltkrn_x.lib (although you'll need the DLL)
- Keep #include "ClassLib/LtWrappr.h"
- Add a linker reference to Ltwvc_x.lib